# JAXP Transformer via DOMSource returns stylesheet

Tags: xml, xslt, jaxp

I'm having a strange problem and can't seem to find any solution. I'm simply trying to apply an XSLT stylesheet to an XML file (in this case, SPARQL query results formatted as XML, but any other XML file gives the same result). In this case, I need to create the transformer by re-using an already loaded XML document, via DOMSource. You can find the code below (simplified; normally, the stylesheet document comes from elsewhere):

```
TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Document stylesheet = db.parse(new File("C:/workspace_5/stylesheet.xml"));
Transformer xformer = factory.newTransformer(new DOMSource(stylesheet));

Source source = new StreamSource(new FileInputStream("C:/workspace_5/xml-file.xml"));        
ByteArrayOutputStream bOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
Result result = new StreamResult(bOut);

xformer.transform(source, result);
```

Instead of the transformed XML, the StreamResult's outputstream returns the loaded stylesheet. If I replace the second and third line by:

```
Transformer xformer = factory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(
    new FileInputStream(""C:/workspace_5/stylesheet.xml")));
```

Then everything works just fine. And yes, of course I could serialize the loaded stylesheet document into a string, convert it to a ByteArrayInputStream (or even worse, write it to a file), and then use that to create a StreamSource, but that's just silly.

Is there any reason this is not working?

The xml-file.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<sparql>
  <head>
    <variable name="buyerName"/>
  </head>
  <results>
    <result>
      <binding name="buyerName">
        <literal>John Doe</literal>
      </binding>
    </result>
  </results>
</sparql>
```

The stylesheet.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:po="http://www.w3.org/2002/ws/sawsdl/spec/wsdl/order#"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<xsl:template match="/sparql">
    <xsl:for-each select="results/result">

        <buyer xsi:type="po:Buyer">
            <name xsi:type="string"><xsl:value-of select="binding[@name='buyerName']/literal" /></name>
        </buyer>

    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thanks!

William

Comment: C'mon guys, this is supposed to be a mature technology.. Nobody has any knowledge or experience on this? :-(

Answer (score 2):

Your DocumentBuilderFactory is most likely not namespace aware.  Try turning on namespace awareness with:

```
factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
```

You can [check out this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12780355/xslt-transformation-passing-parameters/13468540#13468540) for the related code.

Comment: You solved my problem exactly with this answer, so I'm giving you some credit that you should have received two years ago. Thanks @C. Trimble !